# Array Index out of Bound Error when splitting a string

Tags: java

Can someone please help me find the problem with the following code: it keeps giving me an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

code

```
public class Hello{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String tf = "192.168.40.1";
        String[] arggg = tf.split(".");
        String add = arggg[0];
        System.out.println(add);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger? What is the length of `arggg`? What is the parameter for `split` meant to be?

Answer (score 7):

`.` is a special charater in regex. So when using with `split()` method you need to escape it.

Use,

```
String[] arggg = tf.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is the case. Dot is the Reguler Expression and when using Reguler expression with `spilt()` method it splitting using Reguler expression. You can get more detailed idea about it by following http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html link.

What you need to do is use escape charactor and tell split method you need to split using `"."`

```
String[] arggg = tf.split("\\.");
```

will solve your issue.